# Pyserial: could not configure port: (5, 'Input/output error)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyserial

I've been trying to get the following two lines of Python code to run for the past two days, without much success:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(0)
```

Each time I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 4, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 280, in open
    self._reconfigurePort()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 308, in _reconfigurePort
    raise SerialException("Could not configure port: %s" % msg)
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Could not configure port: (5, 'Input/output error')
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, with Pyserial 2.5 (python-serial 2.5-2.1) and Python 2.7 (python 2.7.2-7ubuntu2) and my user is a member of the dialout group.

I run Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit at work too, with the same versions of Python and Pyserial, and the problem doesn't seem to occur there. Any suggestions are welcome - I'm pretty flummoxed...

Thanks,
Donagh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This exception is thrown if the port is not available. On Linux, you can simply specify the exact name of the port to use, like

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. On my system, the format is /dev/ttyS#, where # is in [0,31]. I've tried ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS27') and a few other numbers, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Note that the devices may be there, but not connected to anything. This is no special behavior of pyserial, you can run `cat /dev/ttyS0` to see the same thing. What makes you think that there is at least one serial port connected? And what makes you think that that is `/dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: Aha! That's exactly the problem! I only started playing around with Pyserial a few days ago (I've been trying to set up a virtual port). It never occurred to me that I'd need a physical connection. RTFM. My fault. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: ^, I am having the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, and 15.04. What kind of physical connection do you need?