# Serial port /dev/ttyS0 and ttys* input output error

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, serial-port, pyserial

I'm new to this kind of things so I need help from you guys. When playing around with serial ports, I figured why not echo from one terminal and cat/listen from the other using one of the /dev/ttyS* serial ports on my ubuntu 15.04 laptop. When i do `cat /dev/ttyS0` it gives me input output error. then i tried doing it using pyserial on python. when i do

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0')
```

it gives me `SerialException: Could not configure port: (5, 'Input/output error')`

After looking around on stack overflow, I found this related post [Pyserial: could not configure port: (5, 'Input/output error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181576/pyserial-could-not-configure-port-5-input-output-error)
where one of the guy said you need a physical connection to make this happen. I'm guessing that is to create some kind of loop. So my question is what kind of physical connection is required? Who a usb stick do it, or do i need something dedicated to work with the serial port. And if someone would provide good explanation on how serial port programming works, that would be great.

Feel free to edit the question where you see fit. Guys please no need to complain about how dumb this question sounds and all that. After all lots of people come here to learn, and that is what i am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have one or two physical com or serial ports on your pc to achieve this. if you have one port you can create a loopback plug by connecting the Rx and Tx pins together.

If you don't have a physical serial port and want to test it you can use socat to create a virtual serial port.

Comment: ^ thanks, i will try that. Do you mean socat or scoat?

Comment: It's 'socat' see the manpage for details. You can use 'socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0' to create two virtual serial ports.

Answer (score 0):

Physically you need a cable that swaps the transmit and receive pins.  This is known as a "null-modem cable" because it can connect two computers together without a modem in between.

You probably also need to add yourself to the "dialout" group in order to use the serial ports.

putty is a really good program for testing with serial ports -- you can have two putty instances talking to each other, and then try to connect putty on one side with Python on the other side.

Finally, sometimes there is a modem daemon that will run and think that it should own all the serial ports.  It usually gives up and lets them go after awhile, but you might have to find it and kill it if you don't want random processes polling for modems on your serial connection.

Comment: Great explanation. I did add myself to the dialout group. Since I don't have the physical serial port, i will try creating a virtual one. Thanks a lot.